# Get SSL Cert info that in char * from openssl api

Tags: openssl, pem

Currently, I am getting from server .crt data, I have to decode and print.

I would like to make something like|

```
FILE* f = fopen("brokerca_1.pem", "r");
     if (f != NULL)
     {
         X509* x509 = PEM_read_X509(f, NULL, NULL, NULL);
         if (x509 != NULL)
         {
             char* p = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(x509), 0, 0);
             if (p)
             {
                 printf("NAME: %s\n", p);
                 OPENSSL_free(p);
             }
             X509_free(x509);
         }
     }
```

but using char* not a file, 
any help is appreciated

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you mean to say you want to read the cert from a char* buffer and not from a FILE*? Possible answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985828/switching-from-pem-read-x509-to-pem-read-bio-x509-file-based-to-bio-based-input

Comment: Yes, thats rigth thanks yoy